Overstaying knowing I have a new Schengen visa
I have a valid German Schengen visa expires on October 4th, I plan to go for work and stay after with relatives exceeding my expiry date. I have a new visa though that starts on October 5th.
My question is can I travel with my old visa and overstay knowing I have a new German Schengen visa? Will I get fined or worse banned? I think it should be okay considering I will only overstay considering I have a new Schengen visa to cover the rest of the trip after October the 4th.

How long is the old visa valid for, is it a single entry visa or a multiple entry, and how many days will you have been in the Schengen area at Oct 4th?

What do you mean with overstay? Stay longer than 90 days? Stay through October 5?

@Willeke Why do you think the duration of the old visa or the number of entries could possibly matter?

What types of visa (C, D), and if a D visa, what country issued it/them?

@Relaxed if they have already been in the Schengen 90 day or the number of days their visas allow if less they can not extend the stay by using the new visa. And a single entry visa might have other restrictions that stops using the new visa to stay longer.

@Willeke OK, I understand, I was confused about what you were asking, thanks. The length of stay is relevant but not the period of validity. I now realize that's probably what you meant but “how long is the old visa valid for“ suggested validity to me. And it's also true that a multiple-entry visa is supposed to allow stays of up to 90 days in any 180-day period while single-entry will tend to have restrictions to the maximum allowed stay but the latter is what we really need to know, not the number of entries per say.

So to avoid confusion: What we need to know is the number of days each visa is good for, the number next to the “Dauer des aufenthalts“ / “Duration of stay“ label on the visa sticker:

There is a lot of important info missing from your question but it's reasonably easy to give a comprehensive overview of relevant rules:

You are allowed to stay up to 90 days in any 180-day period with short-stay visas, no exceptions. Even getting a new visa does NOT allow you to go over that limit (but the consulate would usually catch that before granting the visa, unless you tried to hide how long you intend to stay).

Short-stay visas are sometimes limited to a shorter duration of stay (i.e. less than 90 days). In that case, you may not stay for longer than what it says. You will find this info under the “Duration of stay“ rubric on the visa sticker.

If you have two back-to-back Schengen visas, you are allowed to stay in the Schengen area through the end of the validity period of the first one and into the validity period of the second one (again, provided that you abide by the maximum stay rules). You do not need to leave and reenter the area in-between.

In the past, if one of your visas was actually a German long-stay visa (a national visa valid for more than 90 days) instead of a Schengen visa then it might have been required to leave and reenter the country between stays under each visa but that shouldn't be the case anymore. Among other differences, the sticker for national visas say “D” in the “type of visa” rubric.



Certain nationalities are allowed to apply for German D visa from within Germany, but those would be people who do not need a short-stay visa at all.

@o.m. Not really, what you would be applying for in this case is typically a residence permit, skipping the visa step entirely. Note that this also applies to the members of the family of EU citizens residing in Germany, no matter their citizenship. I am not sure I see the connection to this Q&A, though.

You tried to give a general overview, and this is an exception to the "may be required" in point 4.

@o.m. Logically, there cannot be any exception to “may be required”, it's too weak a phrasing for that, that's why I wrote  “may be required” not “must”. Obviously, I said absolutely nothing about applying for the visa but about what could happen when you already have one and, again, your scenario is fanciful, what people would apply for in this situation is a residence permit, not a visa. If you have a D visa, you applied for it before entering the country (not very likely either to be honest), that's what point 4 is about.

Incidentally, we can also rule out this scenario for two other separate reasons: the OP already has two visas and, as you noted yourself, the only people who are allowed to apply for a residence permit within Germany based on their citizenship do not require short-stay visas to visit the Schengen area.

Point 4 should no longer be required since the lastest changes in the Schengen Border Code Article 12 (Presumption as regards fulfilment of conditions of duration of short stay): (3) ... or of the date of expiry of a previous residence permit or long-stay visa, ....

@MarkJohnson Thanks, I had the feeling this was changing but I didn't remember in which direction. Is it already enacted or coming soon?

This was a part of the changes made for EES and came into force on 2024-07-10.

Sorry to 'nickpick' here, but a national visa (Type D) can be valid up to one year. Nothing, anywhere, states that it cannot be valid for less than 90 days.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


My question is can I travel with my old visa and overstay knowing I have a new German Schengen visa?

This is a misconception on your part.
You are allowed to stay for 90 days in any 180-day period, during which (as a visa national) you must also have a valid visa.

Schengen visa expires on October 4th, I plan to go for work and stay after with relatives exceeding my expiry date. I have a new visa though that starts on October 5th.

You have a valid visa(s) that cover your entry, duration and exit (assuming that the duration of the visa is not less than 90 days).
Important is only that the allowed duration is not exceded and that you have, in this case, multiple visas that cover your stay.
